# How does radiation work in Metro Exodus?

Tags: metro-exodus

After the nuclear apocalypse there are pockets of radiation covering Russia. Artyom has a gas mask to protect himself from most of Russia's dangers, but it's use isn't fully explained.

Does radiation exposure in the wasteland have any long-term effects or does it only deal short-term damage?
Similarly, does Artyom need to wear his gas mask when entering all radiation hot zones? If so, does the gas mask reduce or fully negate damage from radiation?

Comment: I feel that a lot of the questions are determinate based on the answer of the previous question or otherwise not wothy of its own post. I'm having difficulty narrowing it down. In your opinion what would you feel the most important question(s) on this list would be?

Comment: Reduced scope; I'll post more questions later today. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being in a radioactive hot-zone and then leaving it alive does not have any long-term effect on the gameplay, just short term damage to your health.

Wearing a gas mask is not related to the radiation hot-zones, it used to prevent inhaling radioactive dust (thus preventing Artyom from suffocating). In the hot-zones the direct radiation is so high it will kill you regardless of you wearing a mask or not.